# Installing Tensorflow: Python - Tensorflow Version Mismatch Warnings

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

EDIT:`tensorflow-1.3.0-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl`
Now getting different warnings. These seem much more minor?

```
2017-11-02 13:31:01.945114: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-11-02 13:31:01.945138: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-11-02 13:31:01.945154: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-11-02 13:31:01.945158: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-11-02 13:31:01.945166: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use FMA instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
```

I'm on Ubuntu 17.10 with Python 3.6.3 installed.
I installed tensorflow wheel file in virtualenv using

```
export TF_BINARY_URL=../Downloads/tensorflow-1.4.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
pip3 install --upgrade $TF_BINARY_URL
```

Then running the example code below to validate install I get a couple of warnings

```
AI/lib/python3.6/importlib/_bootstrap.py:219: RuntimeWarning: compiletime version 3.5 of module 'tensorflow.python.framework.fast_tensor_util' does not match runtime version 3.6
  return f(*args, **kwds)
2017-11-02 12:32:13.054316: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:137] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA
```

The example code seems to run after all errors. Should I just ignore them?
Did I download the wrong wheel file?

```
import tensorflow as tf
hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(hello))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see here for python3.5 TF_Binary_URL is

https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux#the_url_of_the_tensorflow_python_package
 which is tensor version 1.3, so just check with that.

Comment: This didn't work but I changed both 34 to 36 to match my python version. I've updated Original Post with my results.

Comment: I don't think this warning will create any problem in future because these are for computation purpose.if any let me know in future

Comment: Yeah - as far as I understand it is fine now. Just MAY run faster if I compiled from source.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

These are simply warnings and I do not think you will be at a loss if you do ignore them. [There](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7778) is an issue thread in Tensorflow repo about it. They basically mean that if you would have built TF from source in your machine then it could have been faster (only on the CPU aspect. Given the fact that you did not mention GPU, I assume that is what you want.)

You can stop them by doing this `export TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL=2`

Comment: Yeah - I essentially came to this conclusion in my comment above. Thanks for the confirmation/validation.

Comment: I think I know the answer to this question but: Why exactly is it a good practice to use a virtualenv over native/pip?

Comment: I guess what you want to mean is `why is it better to use a virtualenv over system python`. There are many reasons. The main two are 1) You do not mess up with the system python and necessary libraries (the versions also matters. If you update a library something somewhere might break beyond repair)  2) If you do a` pip freeze > requirements.txt` you are mostly sure that you are generating a requirements.txt that closely matches your project and not something that has many other project's requirements blent in.